# How to Recall a Sitecore Pipeline and Processor?

Tags: pipelines

I want to call `EnsureDevice` Processor from `EnsureSessionContext` pipeline after certain conditions met.

```
   public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
   { 
        string countryCode= GetCountryFromIp();
        if (countryCode != "IN" && countryCode != "US")
        {
            if (HasCookieConsent())
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE"] != null)
                {
                    var myCookie = new HttpCookie("SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE");
                    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
                }

                args.AbortPipeline();
            }
            else
            {
                Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run("EnsureSessionContext", new Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineArgs());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your detail should be added to the question , not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same code that it's DLL (`Sitecore.Analytics`) is using it to call the pipeline like this.

```
InitializeTrackerArgs args = new InitializeTrackerArgs();
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    args.HttpContext = (HttpContextBase) new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    args.IsSessionEnd = HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath == "/SESSION END";
}
EnsureSessionContextPipeline.Run(args);
if (args.Aborted || args.Session == null)
    return;
Switcher<Session, Session>.Enter(args.Session);
```

And here is the class that is running this pipeline.

```
public static class EnsureSessionContextPipeline
{
    private static AnalyticsPipelinesPerformanceContextBase _performanceContext;

    internal static AnalyticsPipelinesPerformanceContextBase PerformanceContext
    {
      get => EnsureSessionContextPipeline._performanceContext ?? (EnsureSessionContextPipeline._performanceContext = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AnalyticsPipelinesPerformanceContextBase>());
      set => EnsureSessionContextPipeline._performanceContext = value;
    }

    public static void Run(InitializeTrackerArgs args) => EnsureSessionContextPipeline.PerformanceContext.EnsureSessionContextPerformanceMonitor.Monitor((Action) (() =>
    {
      if (!XdbSettings.Tracking.Enabled)
        return;
      CorePipeline.Run("ensureSessionContext", (PipelineArgs) args);
    }));
}
```

This way you can call the pipeline and it will execute all the processors in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`EnsureSessionContext` pipeline requires `InitializeTrackerArgs` object as an argument. Also, it checks for `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` value. so, it should be `true`.

```
InitializeTrackerArgs initializeTrackerArgs = new InitializeTrackerArgs();
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run("ensureSessionContext", initializeTrackerArgs);
```

Another way to call EnsureSessionContextPipeline.

```
InitializeTrackerArgs initializeTrackerArgs = new InitializeTrackerArgs();
EnsureSessionContextPipeline.Run(initializeTrackerArgs);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to call ensureDevice processor under EnsureSessionContext Pipeline, Is there any way to get there

Comment: EnsureSessionContext pipeline has a number of processors and it is dependent on each other in terms of processing things in such order. I'd advise calling a pipeline instead of the specific processor to execute things in the right order and avoid any errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of calling a single processor from a chosen pipeline. That's the whole point of pipelines - pipelines define a sequence of processors. They should be executed in a specific order as arguments which are passed through the pipeline, can be changed in processors executed at the beginning of the pipeline and further processors will use those values.

Will all the above said, you can always try to create an instance of a processor class, create object of args class and just call `Process` method, but that's unusual approach and I don't think you should ever do that.

E.g. when it comes to `EnsureDevice` processor, it must have `args.Session` set earlier, otherwise there will `Assert.ArgumentNotNull` error. And `args.Session` is normally set from `EnsureContext` processor which is called earlier in `EnsureSessionContext` pipeline.